# Send result from HTTP request in Angular to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, request

I am currently sending a request from NodeJS to get some data, as such :

In Angular :

```
$http.post(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/annonce', {'link': url}).then(function (result) {
...
}
```

And in Node :

```
apiRoutes.post('/annonce', function (req, res) {
  const url = req.body.link

  request.get({
    uri: url,
    encoding: null
  }, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error) {
      res.send(parser(url, html))
    }
  })

  return res
})
```

I would like to send this request from my front-end (Angular). I guess I could simply do the request like this :

```
$http.get(url).then(function(result)) {
    // send another post request to the back end with the result
}
```

but I've heard it was easier to use [pipes](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) in this case.
Thing is, I really don't understand how to make it work. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are trying to retrieve does not have the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) headers then angular will fail to make the request.

If you expand on your usecase it should be easier to get you some help.

Comment: Basically what I'm building here is a scraper. The user provides a URL, and my tool fetches information on the targetted website.
Some websites don't like when too many requests come from the same URL (to prevent DDOS I'm guessing), so I would like to do the GET requests from the front-end, so that the request doesn't always come from my server.
Right now it's working like this (with the requests sent from the backend)